# Trouble opening a WMF file

Tags: images, file-corruption, vector-graphics, image-formats, wmf

I've gotten this WMF file which (probably) contains an image, somehow. I saved it out of a .docx file opened in Libreoffice, so it can't be entirely corrupt (I think). If I run `file` on it, I get:

```
$ file /tmp/sg30.xyz.wmf 
/tmp/sg30.xyz.wmf: Windows Enhanced Metafile (EMF) image data version 0x10000
```

but both Inkscape and [wmf2svg](https://github.com/hidekatsu-izuno/wmf2svg/) seem to think it's corrupt. What do I do?

Comment: How large is the file? WMF is more commonly a video format. Do you know that this one is a static image?

Comment: Try extracting it by [changing the .docx extension to .zip](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/explore-the-contents-of-a-docx-file-in-windows-7/) and see if its a problem with extracting via LibreOffice.

Comment: @music2myear: It's 30920 bytes.

Comment: @AdamLimbert: The .docx is gone...

Comment: Try to change the file from `.wmf` to `.emf`.